# Rails before_validation strip whitespace best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I would like my User model to sanitize some input before before save. For now some simple whitespace stripping will do. 
So to avoid people registering with "Harry " and pretend to be "Harry", for example.

I assume it is a good idea to do this stripping before validation, so that the validates_uniqueness_of can avoid accidental duplicates.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :open_ids

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i

  before_validation :strip_whitespace, :only => [:name, :email, :nick]

  private
  def strip_whitespace(value)
    value.responds_to?('strip') ? value.strip : value
  end
end
```

However, this code comes with an error ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1). I assumed the callback would be passed the values.

Also: is this stripping actually a good idea? Or should I rather validate on space and tell the user that "Harry  " contains invalid spacess (I want to allow "Harry Potter" but not "Harry\s\sPotter").

Edit: As pointed out in a comment, my code is wrong (which is why I was asking the question a.o.). Please make sure you read the accepted answer in addition to my question for the correct code and to avoid the same mistakes I made.

Comment: For others stumbling upon this - before_validation does not have an `:only` option.  And the callback does not take an argument.  See answers for more details.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I don't believe `before_validation` works like that. You probably want to write your method like this instead:

```
def strip_whitespace
  self.name = self.name.strip unless self.name.nil?
  self.email = self.email.strip unless self.email.nil?
  self.nick = self.nick.strip unless self.nick.nil?
end
```

You could make it more dynamic if you want using something like `self.columns`, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: I added an unless self.name.blank? behind them, to avoid stripping NIL-values.

Comment: Depending on your class you can consider 
```ruby
def strip_whitespace
  self.email = email.strip
end
```

Comment: @berkes - I'd be better to add `if self.name.respond_to?(:strip)`.

Comment: `strip` does not handle Unicode space characters. See https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7845. As of Ruby 2.3.0 the issue is still present.

Comment: I realize this is very old, but I wanted to point out two things.. First, instead of `self.name = self.name.strip unless self.name.nil?`, I've come to prefer `self.name.try(&:strip!)`.  But if you are really looking to remove whitespace from the beginning and end, I find `self.name.gsub! /(\A\s*|\s*\z)/, ''` to be most reliable.

Comment: @chad_ why do not you post your answer with some explanations?

Comment: This answer is fine but I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47208303/199712) is even better.

Answer (score 51):

There are several gems to do this automatically. Those gems work in the similar way of creating callback in before_validation. One good gem is at https://github.com/holli/auto_strip_attributes

```
gem "auto_strip_attributes", "~> 2.2"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  auto_strip_attributes :name, :nick, nullify: false, squish: true
  auto_strip_attributes :email
end
```

Stripping is often a good idea. Especially for leading and trailing whitespaces. User often creates trailing spaces when copy/pasting value to a form. With names and other identifying strings you also might want squish the string. So that "Harry     Potter" will become "Harry Potter" (squish option in the gem).

Answer (score 30):

Charlie's answer is good, but there's a little verbosity. Here's a tighter version:

```
def clean_data
  # trim whitespace from beginning and end of string attributes
  attribute_names.each do |name|
    if send(name).respond_to?(:strip)
      send("#{name}=", send(name).strip)
    end
  end
end
```

The reason we use

```
self.foo = "bar"
```

instead of

```
foo = "bar"
```

in the context of ActiveRecord objects is that Ruby interprets the latter as a local variable assignment. It will just set the foo variable in your method scope, instead of calling the "foo=" method of your object.

But if you are calling a method, there is no ambiguity. The interpreter knows you're not referring to a local variable called foo because there is none. So for example with:

```
self.foo = foo + 1
```

you need to use "self" for the assignment, but not to read the current value.

Comment: I'm using this but with `changed.each` instead of `attributes_names` to limit it to the fields that were changed.

Answer (score 23):

I'd like to add one pitfall that you might experience with the "before_validations" solutions above. Take this example:

```
u = User.new(name: " lala")
u.name # => " lala"
u.save
u.name # => "lala"
```

This means you have an inconsistent behavior based on whether your object was saved or not. If you want to address this, I suggest another solution to your problem: overwriting the corresponding setter methods.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name=(name)
    write_attribute(:name, name.try(:strip))
  end
end
```

I also like this approach because it does not force you to enable stripping for all attributes that support it - unlike the `attribute_names.each` mentioned earlier. Also, no callbacks required.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ben. I'm using the abovementioned approach in Rails 3 without any problems. Also, it still is the approach mentioned in the docs for 3.2.8: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html. Did you experience any issues with it?

Answer (score 12):

Instead  we can write a better method more generic regardless whatever may be the type of attributes with the object(might have 3 string type fields, few booleans, few numeric)

```
before_validation :strip_input_fields


def strip_input_fields
  self.attributes.each do |key, value|
    self[key] = value.strip if value.respond_to?("strip")
  end
end
```

Hope that will helps someone!

Comment: respond_to?() is a charm!!! I'm using squish instead of strip, because it also transforms few spaces in one inside of the string

Answer (score 10):

### [StripAttributes Gem](https://github.com/rmm5t/strip_attributes)

I used [strip_attributes](https://github.com/rmm5t/strip_attributes). It's really awesome and easy to implement.

#### Default Behavior

```
class DrunkPokerPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  strip_attributes
end
```

By default, this will only strip the leading and trailing whitespaces and will act on all attributes of the model. This is ideal because it's not destructive and doesn't require you to specify which attributes need to be striped.

#### Using `except`

```
# all attributes will be stripped except :boxers
class SoberPokerPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  strip_attributes :except => :boxers
end
```

#### Using `only`

```
# only :shoe, :sock, and :glove attributes will be stripped
class ConservativePokerPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  strip_attributes :only => [:shoe, :sock, :glove]
end
```

#### Using `allow_empty`

```
# Empty attributes will not be converted to nil
class BrokePokerPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  strip_attributes :allow_empty => true
end
```

#### Using `collapse_spaces`

```
# Sequential spaces in attributes will be collapsed to one space
class EloquentPokerPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  strip_attributes :collapse_spaces => true
end
```

#### Using regex

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Strip off characters defined by RegEx
  strip_attributes :only => [:first_name, :last_name], :regex => /[^[:alpha:]\s]/
  # Strip off non-integers
  strip_attributes :only => [:phone], :regex => /[^0-9]/
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to that gem, but seems it only works up to Rails 3.2

Comment: @rmcsharry From the current `.gemspec`, it looks like it works from Rails 3 - Rails 5: `"activemodel", ">= 3.0", "< 6.0"`

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Thanks for the info, I guess it was updated.

Answer (score 10):

Starting with Ruby 2.3.0 you can use the Safe Navigation Operator(&.)

```
before_validation :strip_whitespace

def strip_whitespace
  self.name&.strip!
  self.email&.strip!
  self.nick&.strip!
end
```

GEMS:
https://github.com/rmm5t/strip_attributes/
https://github.com/holli/auto_strip_attributes/

Answer (score 9):

I like Karl's answer, but is there a way to do it without referencing each of the attributes by name? That is, is there a way to just run through the model attributes and call strip on each one (if it responds to that method)?

This would be desirable so I don't have to update the remove_whitespace method whenever I change the model.

**UPDATE**

I see that Karl implied that you might want to do this sort of thing. I didn't immediately know how it could be done, but here's something that works for me as described above. There' probably a better way to do it, but this works:

```
def clean_data
  # trim whitespace from beginning and end of string attributes
  attribute_names().each do |name|
  if self.send(name.to_sym).respond_to?(:strip)
    self.send("#{name}=".to_sym, self.send(name).strip)
  end
end
```

end

Comment: that looks like a superior solution, and worked great, thanks

Comment: Great solution. But it can be optimized more: instead of attributes_names method we can use changes.keys so second time only changed attributes can be stripped.

Answer (score 9):

If you have access to ActiveSupport, use squish instead of strip.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish

Comment: Damn, I'd never noticed this method before. A useful one! Although it's worth noting that you might not *always* want to use `squish` instead of `strip`, e.g. for a long piece of text like a blog post you probably want to preserve the user's inner whitespace.

Comment: **Careful with this** as it will remove any multiple spaces and remove any newlines as well. Certainly not what you want most of the time when accepting user input and a lot more invasive than just stripping the leading and trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 9):

Ruby on Rails 7.1 introduced [`ActiveRecord::Base::normalizes`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43945) which allows defining data sanitization callbacks like this:

```
normalizes :name, :email, :nick, with: ->(value) { value.strip }
```

This method is able to handle `nil` values and will per default not call the normalization lambda when the value is `nil`. That means no extra check for `nil` required.

When the normalization should be called for `nil` values too, then you can set `apply_to_nil: true`, to do stuff like this

```
normalize :name, apply_to_nil: true, with: ->(name) { name&.strip || 'NN' }
```

which would normalize the `name` attribute by stripping whitespace if a `name` is set, otherwise it would set the `name` to the string `"NN"`

Answer (score 7):

Overriding the attribute write methods is another good way. For example:

```
class MyModel
  def email=(value)
    super(value.try(:strip))
  end
end
```

Then any part of the application that sets the value will have it stripped, including assign_attributes and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative approach, if you are mostly concerned with users mis-entering data in your front-end forms...

```
# app/assets/javascripts/trim.inputs.js.coffee
$(document).on "change", "input", ->
  $(this).val $(this).val().trim()
```

Then include the file in your application.js if you aren't already including the whole tree.

This will ensure that every input gets leading & trailing whitespace removed before it is submitted to be saved by Rails. It's bound on `document`, and delegated to inputs, so any inputs added to the page later will be processed as well.

**Pros:**

- Does not require listing individual attributes by name
- Does not require any metaprogramming
- Does not require external library dependencies

**Cons:**

- Data submitted any other way than the forms (eg, via API) will not be trimmed
- Does not have advanced features like squish (but you could add that yourself)
- As mentioned in comments, does not work if JS is disabled (but who codes for that?)

Comment: Nice addition. Thanks. Though this will also catch passwords, where people might deliberately add a space. After which that space gets magically removed. IMHO any password-field should be excluded from the JS-trimming.

Comment: Regardless what validations/clean up are present on client side, backend has to do its own.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment yet, I'll have to ask here: which method is giving the ArgumentError? `strip`, or `responds_to?`

Also, `.strip` removes only leading and trailing whitespace. If you want "Harry Potter" with two spaces to not be accepted, you would either have to use a regex or, more simply, you could call .split, which removes spaces, and re-concatenate the string with a single space.

As far as if stripping is a good idea, I don't see a problem when it is just the leading/trailing whitespace. If there are multiple spaces in between words though, I would notify the user instead of automatically removing the extra spaces and giving the user a login that is not what they submitted.

Comment: My guess is `strip_whitespace` is throwing the error. You don't pass along values to the validation callbacks because the record gets passed. I don't believe you can do the `:only` style, either.

Comment: About the two-spaces-in-the-middle: yes, that is what I will add later in validations. 
About the method that throws the error: that is strip_whitespace itself.

Answer (score 1):

Another gem option is [attribute_normalizer](https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer):

```
# By default it will strip leading and trailing whitespace
# and set to nil if blank.
normalize_attributes :author, :publisher
```

> :strip Will strip leading and trailing whitespace.

```
normalize_attribute  :author, :with => :strip
```

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative is to overwrite the setter method and use `value.squish`. Its cleaner and you don't have to use before_validation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name=(value)
    super(value.squish)
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails 7.1 [introduced](https://github.com/jonathanhefner/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/normalization.rb) `ActiveRecord::Base::normalizes`

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  normalizes :email, with: ->(email) { email.strip.downcase }
end
```

It invokes before validation

It is safe because doesn't (but optionally can) apply to `nil`

```rb
User.create(email: " ASDF@ExAmPLE.com \n")
# => #<User email: "asdf@example.com">

User.find_by(email: "\nasdf@examplE.CoM \t")
# => #<User email: "asdf@example.com">
```

If you have legacy non-normalized record, you can normalize it with `ActiveRecord::Base#normalize_attribute`

```
user.email # => "legacy@EMAIL.com  "
user.normalize_attribute(:email)
user.email # => "legacy@email.com"
user.save
```