# How to restrict white/blank spaces in an input field in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, whitespace

I want to put restriction on a field so that user cannot enter white/blank space. I have tried multiple solutions but nothing works.

Following are some solutions that I have tried -

```
validates :promo_code, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/ }
```

```
normalize_attribute :promo_code, :with => :strip
```

```
validate :check_empty_space

def check_empty_space
  if self.promo_code.match(/\s+/)
    errors.add(:attribute, "No empty spaces please :(")
  end
end
```

```
 validates :promo_code, format: { without: /\s/, message: "must contain no spaces" }
```

> [Rails before_validation strip whitespace best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268053/rails-before-validation-strip-whitespace-best-practices)

Please suggest something that actually works.

Comment: Try to use `errors.add(:promo_code, "No empty spaces please :(")` instead of :attribute

Comment: @Toni It is still not working.

Comment: What does this return if you debug the validation: `self.promo_code.match(/\s+/)`. If object is return, you have space in the string.

You can also try with `self.promo_code =~ /\s/`, which should return the index of first space found. So if that condition returns any number, string has spaces, if returns "nil", string has no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I got the following validation working to prevent having whitespaces:

```rb
validates :promo_code, format: { without: /\s/, message: 'No empty spaces please :(' }
```

If that's not working for you, then please add the version of rails you are using.

Comment: The rails version that I am using is 4.2.11.3

Comment: Looks like that version should work the same way. Can you tell me how did you try it? Did you create a new record without putting anything into the input or did you add text with a space?

Comment: This input field is compulsory so I have added the text with a space and it is still allowing the whitespaces.

Comment: If you go into your rails console and you build a new record with spaces inside the promo_code without saving it and call `.valid?` on it, does it returns true or false?

Comment: It is returning false.

Comment: That means your validation is working and you skip validations when you create it with your form. Can you show the piece of code from the controller where you are saving it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241210/discussion-between-hackman-and-user).